# Space between elements. How to avoid spacing the first item?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 text fields, and I'm trying to make a 10px space between them. I got it to work, but the first item has moved 10px too, and I don't want it to. I thought about class for the last 3 text fields, which will work, but I'm still looking for a better idea. Any suggestions?

**HTML:**

```
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span {
    margin:0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Add a class for first and last item and use these classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:first-child` pseudo selector:

```
span:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
```

`:first-child` selects (in this case) the first `<span>` that is the **first child** of it's parent (`<body>`) in our case, and applies styling to that element only. Same goes for `:last-child`, which applies styling to **the last child** of it's parent.

Also, using the `:last-child` selector should divide everything equally, please keep in mind to be symmetric, you'll have apply margin-left and right to elements as well, a small example:

```css
span {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

span:first-child {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0; // right 10px
}

span:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px; // left 10px
}
```

```html
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

A better solution to avoid `margin` for the first element is to us CSS's `:not` selector,

> The :not(selector) selector matches every element that is NOT the
>   specified element/selector.

Leaving the first span tag, the other three should have `margin-right` and `margin-left` of `10px`. We can do this with the `:not` selector:

```css
span:not(:first-child) {
    margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
```

Comment: Or even combine them `:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)` to save lines :).

Comment: Yes @Roberrrt but here OP wants to perform that on first tag :-)

Answer (score 2):

Change the css:

```
span:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}

span {
    margin:0 10px;
}
```

The `:first-child` pseudo selector will give a different margin to the first `span` element.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way to exclude the first one :) :

```css
span + span {
    margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
```